# Pyramid on Google’s App Engine using buildout resulting in setuptools not found error

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, pyramid

I am trying to run pyramid application on google's app engine using buildout. I followed this link [gae_buildout](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/en/latest/deployment/gae_buildout.html) and got struck while running the buildout. Its shows "setuptools not found error" despite of seetuptools being installed in the virtual environment. I tried few work arounds and nothing turned fruitful, any thoughts on this ?

Find the error trace below. I am using pyramid 1.4 version.

```
An internal error occurred due to a bug in either zc.buildout or in a
recipe being used:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\myenv\newproject\eggs\zc.buildout-2.2.1-py2.7.egg\zc\buildout\buildou
t.py", line 1942, in main
    getattr(buildout, command)(args)
  File "c:\myenv\newproject\eggs\zc.buildout-2.2.1-py2.7.egg\zc\buildout\buildou
t.py", line 622, in install
    installed_files = self[part]._call(recipe.install)
  File "c:\myenv\newproject\eggs\zc.buildout-2.2.1-py2.7.egg\zc\buildout\buildou
t.py", line 1366, in _call
    return f()
  File "c:\myenv\newproject\eggs\rod.recipe.appengine-2.0.2-py2.7.egg\rod\recipe
\appengine\__init__.py", line 377, in install
    self.copy_packages(ws, temp_dir)
  File "c:\myenv\newproject\eggs\rod.recipe.appengine-2.0.2-py2.7.egg\rod\recipe
\appengine\__init__.py", line 284, in copy_packages
    self.write_pkg_resources(ws, lib)
  File "c:\myenv\newproject\eggs\rod.recipe.appengine-2.0.2-py2.7.egg\rod\recipe
\appengine\__init__.py", line 267, in write_pkg_resources
    assert len(setuptools_eggs) == 1, "setuptools not found"
AssertionError: setuptools not found
```

Comment: Why not just open an issue on the gae_buildout issue tracker?

Comment: Isn't that recipe meant to set up a **development** environment? I don't think buildout is supported *on the app engine* **at all**.

Comment: That  buildout recipe is for for appengine - building the dev environment.  I would open the issue. You could just add setup_tools to the buildout.cfg.   I have used rod.recipe.appengine in the past but I have not used  gae_buildout.

Comment: @TimHoffman thanks for the reply. I tried adding setuptools in buildout.cfg yet i couldn't get through the process. Can you provide me an alternative solution if any. Thanks in advance.

Comment: author of pyramid_appengine here, I think due to the setuptools/distribute/merge and ae not having setuptools and now it does, there's a change in ros.recipe.appengine needed http://code.google.com/p/rodrecipes/issues/detail?id=17

Comment: Thanks @TomWillis now i could not see this error but proceeding further i am getting the below error(mentioned in comment for Enric's answer). Any thoughts on this?

Comment: would you mind reporting errors on github where I can track them better? I kind of need more context then what a little comment box provides. https://github.com/twillis/pyramid_appengine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the same (Ubuntu 12.04) and finally solved the problem by changing ae-sdk-version to 1.8.0 from buildout.cfg

Open buildout.cfg and change the line:

```
ae-sdk-version=1.7.5
```

to:

```
ae-sdk-version=1.8.0
```

...or the latest one from [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads). Now seems to be 1.8.5, but 1.8.0 worked for me.

The problem in fact comes because PyPI is not serving last version of **pyramid_appengine**. It's serving 0.8.1 and should be (latest) 0.8.2-a2. You can download and install in your virtualenv the latest version in a tarball from here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyramid_appengine/

Comment: i tried changing the version and applying the patch given above but i am getting the following error   `\appengine\__init__.py", line 301, in copy_packages
    raise KeyError, '%s: package not found.' % p
KeyError: 'mako: package not found.` Any thoughts on this?? thanks in advance.

Comment: try downloading the latest pyramid_appengine template: `$ myenv/bin/pip install pyramid_appengine==0.8.2-a2` . Create a new project and make the buildout as explained in the tutorial. You should not need the ae-sdk-version tweak

Comment: I am using pyramid_appengine version 0.8.2-a2 , pyramid version 1.4, setuptools version 1.1.6 and yes on using pyramid_appengine latest version GAE is auomatically switched to version 1.8.0 yet i am getting the above error. Raised the same in github (https://github.com/twillis/pyramid_appengine/issues/28#issuecomment-25567428 ). I am trying the steps given by Tom Willis and will let know once its resolved. Many Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the patch is still needed. Hope it is soon solved in the PyPI repo. In the meantime the patch from Tim works fine.

Comment: sorry, I meant the patch from @tom-willis http://code.google.com/p/rodrecipes/issues/detail?id=17

Answer (score 0):

So here's another solution.

It seems that rod.recipe.appengine doesn't work with the setuptools versions of the system, and it doesn't download the last version in that buildout. So the solution is to force to download a newer version of setuptools that rod.recipe.appengine likes.

Edit the versions.cfg file (should appear just the [versions] tag) and add the following line:

```
[versions]
setuptools = 1.1.7
```

(other older versions work as well, I tested successfully with 0.9.8)

And now seems to work easier without needing the mentioned patches (thanks Tom) that are harder to update.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well.

I started looking at the code and noticed it was explicitly looking for an egg install of setuptools, and none of the places I had installations of it were eggs for some reason.

I decided I'd go delete them from my site-packages and re-run the tools to download them, and after only killing the copy in my virtual env, and re-running the bootstrap and buildout, it got the egg and everything started working fine.

Comment: By the way, I also ended up do what Enric Mieza suggested, earlier to fix a different problem where it couldn't find the zip. I guess they deprecated the old build and replaced it with a dummy zip file.