# "_run_file" Error with pyramid buildout for Google App Engine in Ubuntu

Tags: google-app-engine, pyramid, buildout

I built a new project using [buildout for Pyramid and GAE](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/en/latest/deployment/gae_buildout.html) under Ubuntu 12.04 (using *pyramid_appenegine* pcreate template). I started a new VM to ensure no messing with distribute and setuptools in site-packages.

First of all, it results in that [setuptools not found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036180/pyramid-on-googles-app-engine-using-buildout-resulting-in-setuptools-not-found), apparently solved with the [patch provided by Tom Willis](http://code.google.com/p/rodrecipes/issues/detail?id=17).

Then, buildout finishes building ok, but starting the develop site results in that error:

```
funky@funkydesktop:~/dev/gae1$ bin/devappserver parts/gae1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/devappserver", line 25, in <module>
    sys.exit(dev_appserver._run_file('/home/funky/dev/gae1/parts/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py', locals()))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_run_file'
```

Any hints to solve that one, or the whole process of building and starting the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem by changing ae-sdk-version to 1.8.0.

Open buildout.cfg and change the line

```
ae-sdk-version=1.7.5
```

to:

```
ae-sdk-version=1.8.0
```

Or either you could see what happens with pyramid_appengine version (I got 0.8.1 instead of 0.8.2-a2 which is the current one in pypi.python.org). This is the package that holds the template.